Creating tags (or nodes) with a Namespace PL/SQL
The following PL/SQL block...
DECLARE
   doc_   dbms_XmlDom.DomDocument := Dbms_XmlDom.newDomDocument;
   nd_    dbms_XmlDom.DomNode;
   nd2_   dbms_XmlDom.DomNode;
   tag_   dbms_XmlDom.DomElement;
   out_   VARCHAR2(32000);
   ns_    VARCHAR2(20) := 'cp';
BEGIN
   Dbms_XmlDom.setVersion (doc_, '1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes');
   tag_ := Dbms_XmlDom.createElement (
      doc     => doc_,
      tagName => 'coreProperties',
      ns      => ns_
   );
   nd2_ := Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode (tag_);
   nd_  := Dbms_XmlDom.appendChild (Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode(doc_), nd2_);

   out_ := Dbms_XmlDom.getXmlType(doc_).getClobVal;
   Dbms_XmlDom.freeDocument (doc_);
   Dbms_Output.Put_Line (out_);
END;

... produces this XML output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<coreProperties/>

I would expect it to create this output instead (i.e. with the tag-name being namespaced)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties/>

I know I can change the createElement() call to generate the desired output
--- blah...
   tag_ := Dbms_XmlDom.createElement (
      doc     => doc_,
      tagName => ns_ || ':coreProperties'
   );
--- blah

... but that seems silly when there's a documented ns parameter that's expecting data to be passed into it.  (It also becomes a little verbose and messy in a real-world setting).
What am I missing here?  What am I doing wrong?
(Tested in Oracle Free 23ai, but should be backwardly compatible to Oracle 11)

Your desired XML is not well-formed. Before any XML namespace could be used, it shall be declared. It is impossible to use a namespace without its declaration first.

@YitzhakKhabinsky There's always one!!  I know the XML in this fabricated example is not "real" or a correctly formatted document.  But that's not the point is it!!  The question is about the Oracle (PL/SQL) functions, not about how to structure XML documents.

Please edit your question, and provide a realistic well-formed desired output XML.

@YitzhakKhabinsky My question is fine.  It is you who have missed the point.

You can add a prefix to your node with the setPrefix procedure - in your example this works against either nd_ or nd2_:
Dbms_XmlDom.setPrefix (nd_, ns_);

And you can declare the namespace with setAttribute, which you may already know:
Dbms_XmlDom.setAttribute(tag_, 'xmlns:cp', 'http://example.com');

Adding those to your code gives you:
DECLARE
   doc_   dbms_XmlDom.DomDocument := Dbms_XmlDom.newDomDocument;
   nd_    dbms_XmlDom.DomNode;
   nd2_   dbms_XmlDom.DomNode;
   tag_   dbms_XmlDom.DomElement;
   out_   VARCHAR2(32000);
   ns_    VARCHAR2(20) := 'cp';
BEGIN
   Dbms_XmlDom.setVersion (doc_, '1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes');
   tag_ := Dbms_XmlDom.createElement (
      doc     => doc_,
      tagName => 'coreProperties',
      ns      => ns_
   );
   Dbms_XmlDom.setAttribute(tag_, 'xmlns:cp', 'http://example.com');
   nd2_ := Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode (tag_);
   nd_  := Dbms_XmlDom.appendChild (Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode(doc_), nd2_);
   Dbms_XmlDom.setPrefix (nd_, ns_);

   out_ := Dbms_XmlDom.getXmlType(doc_).getClobVal;
   Dbms_XmlDom.freeDocument (doc_);
   Dbms_Output.Put_Line (out_);
END;
/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="http://example.com"/>

fiddle (as 21c, also works the same in 23ai and 11gR2)

You're right.  You need to add the namespace twice in that case.  If you omit the ns parameter from createElement(), then the setPrefix() doesn't do so on its own.  Totally odd way of building an XML engine.

Yes. I'm not sure if that makes more sense with a more complicated document with child nodes. As you can apply to either nd_ or nd2_ that suggests inheritance; but still having to add it to each element gives you the option of having a mix of namespace and non-namespace child nodes? Not sure, and I haven't experimented... all good fun though...

I suspect you're right.  There are probably use cases that warrant the way it's designed.

It could be easier to use the following method.
A commented line with the BLOB is needed in case if you need an encoding specified in the output XML.
SQL
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT
        XMLELEMENT("cp:coreProperties"    
                     , XMLATTRIBUTES('https://yourURL' as "xmlns:cp")    
                     , XMLELEMENT ("cp:city", 'Miami')    
                     , XMLELEMENT ("cp:Info", XMLATTRIBUTES ('Orlando' as "id"))    
                    )  
--AS BLOB encoding 'ISO-8859-1' version '1.0' INDENT SIZE = 4) as XML               
AS CLOB version '1.0' INDENT SIZE = 4) as XML               
FROM dual

Output
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="https://yourURL">
    <cp:city>Miami</cp:city>
    <cp:Info id="Orlando"/>
</cp:coreProperties>


Completely missing the point of doing it in PL/SQL (as opposed to SQL).  And besides, the fundamental answer that you're offering is exactly the alternative that I proposed in the original question.
